# Android XMPP - not receiving messages after an hour of idle mode

Tags: android, xmpp

I have a service that runs every min to check if the global XMPPConnection object is connected and authenticated. What I found is that after an hour or so of idle mode, the connection object shows it is connected and authenticated but it does not receive any messages.

The connection seems to be broken without the Connection object knowing about it. Please let me know what I could implement to check if the XMPPConnection object is truly connected and can receive messages even after a long while of inactivity.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: are you sure your service is running in background ? I am not sure it is issue of xmpp

Comment: Yes, my service is running in the background. I have written a piece of code to create a file everytime it runs, along with timestamp and I see it getting created every min. And in the file, I am logging values of isConnected() and isAuthenticated(), both are TRUE all the time. But they are not receiving.

Comment: how rarely you are facing these issue ? and what service you are using binderService or service

Comment: I am facing this issue if I don't use the phone for more than an hour. I see from the logs that the object shows it is connected but pings don't reach it. I am using Service. I can see in Settings that the service is still running. And of course, from the timestamp of the log entries as well I know that the service is still running.

Answer (score 0):

hi If you are using openfire then go to Server settings then Client connection and change settings to `Do not disconnect clients that are idle`.

This help you to user available all times.

Second solution for your problem if you are not using any service for making user online. Then do that thing.

Here i made example of one to one chat and it available on [github](https://github.com/saveendhiman/XMPPSample_Studio).

thanks hope this help you.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I have already made that setting and I see the user online when I check in the Admin console, but the actual connection is broken and so the connection object does not receive any ping. I am using a Service to connect to the server. The service is also alive, as is evident from the log entries that it makes.

Comment: Can you check my code its working fine. You are missing something.

Comment: Sure, I will try that. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on your XMPP server implementation, you can simply send message to yourself and check if you receive it.

Another way would be to perform XMPP service discovery, fetch your roster list etc. in short - do something that requires client-server communication.

Comment: What is the optimal approach to send such a test message - in terms of frequency, type of ping etc, such that the impact on data usage is minimal ?

Comment: Empty message is still a message :) as for data usage there will always be XMPP Stanza overhead (so no big difference between ping and message). As for frequency, pick the one that suits your needs. 30 minutes would be reasonable (as u stated 60 mins is the limit) and i would perform extra check when app goes foreground.

Comment: If you have access to the server you can always write your own xmpp service that will do whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I will try sending a ping every 30mins and see if that works.

Comment: As you are using most probably `SMACK` for xmpp, you can send even empty IQ - error will be thrown if connection is broken. But to be honest i think that your problem lies somewhere else, and the connection is more than fine.

Comment: Yes, I am using Smack. If your opinion is that the problem might be elsewhere, I will probe more. When I turn N/w off and then on after an hour's idle time, it re-connects and works fine. Till then, it shows the connection object is  good and authenticated but broken somewhere.

Comment: Will the context used to create the XMPPConnection object have a bearing ? I am using getApplicationContext() to create the connection.